# Integration by parts

Tags: quantum-field-theory, calculus

Zee in his book, Quantum field in a nutshell mentioned the following, p. 22:

Equation (14): $$Z=\int{D\phi}e^{i\int d^4x{ {\frac{1}{2}[(\partial \phi)^2-m^2\phi^2]+J\phi}} }$$
He said then, integrating by parts under the $$\int d^4x$$, we write $$Z=\int{D\phi}e^{i\int d^4x{ {(-\frac{1}{2}\phi[(\partial ^2+m^2)\phi+J\phi}} }$$

My question is how did he do this? What does he mean by integration by parts under
$$\int d^4x$$ How does it differ from integration by parts under $$\int d^x$$?

Thanks!!

Comment: Uh...I believe he just wanted to make clear that we are not doing integration by parts w.r.t. the $\int\mathcal{D}\phi$.

Comment: Oh if so, what do I choose to be derived and what to be integrated in the table of integration by parts? @ACuriousMind

Comment: $\int d^x~~~~?$

Comment: @Qmechanic excuse me, what is it that is not clear about the question?

Answer (score 0):

Zee just wants to distinguish the integration $\int \mathrm{d}^4x$ from the integration $\int \mathcal{D}\phi$ when calling this "integration by parts under $\int \mathrm{d}^4x$". As for how the integration by parts itself works, observe that, for any function $f$ vanishing at $\pm\infty$:

$$ \int f'(x)f'(x)\mathrm{d}x = f(x)f'(x)\rvert^\infty_{-\infty} - \int f(x)f''(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int f(x)f''(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

Zee's statement is just the higher-dimensional version of this.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I am familiar with the equation you wrote but I am finding difficulty applying it. What should I choose as my f'(x)?

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics: Set $f = \phi$.